# Image overlaping image in Shader

Tags: image, scene

The attached screenshot shows a whirlwind effect appearing behind the moon. I want it appearing in front of the moon.  How do I adjust a certain image to overlap another image in Shader ?   I want it appearing in front of the moon. Is it a case of a hierarchy adjustment in the Scene Collection window ?
[image]

Comment: please provide blend file

Comment: Here is a link: https://www.mediafire.com/file/3livuvlnff9ztm5/Test.blend/file   But I also noticed Blender saved another (same) file at the same time ... not sure why .... here it is: https://www.mediafire.com/file/pvnva9qib5l3x06/Test.blend1/file

Comment: By the way, just a another quick question:  You will see in the blender file another moon (left one) ... I intentionally decided to drag and drop that moon png file from a pc folder into the blender scene. I noticed that when I select that moon and try to work on it in Shader, I can't add any nodes at all. I tried converting it to mesh but still no Shader nodes available to select. Do you have to do something with those images when you drag and drop them into Blender before you can then add nodes in shader to work on them ?

Comment: please use "file"->"external data"->"pack all into blendfile", then save your blend file and upload again. thank you.

Comment: ok here are the links after having done what you instructed me to do: https://www.mediafire.com/file/3wi56znjqoy04qt/Test.blend/file and https://www.mediafire.com/file/dsuyd10eyv97scq/Test.blend1/file   Still not sure why the are 2 files produced by blender.

Comment: so you want the beach as background, the moon before that and the whirlwind before all?

Comment: @Steb please use the [edit] button below your question to add any new information (files, ect) This is not like a forum where information collects below the original post. Please read the [tour] to learn more about the site and how to best benefit from it.

Comment: @Chris,  correct

Comment: @Timaroberts, in future I will use that edit button when adding extra images or additional information that I left out in the original comment. I assume though message replies to people can simply be added using the Add Comment button.

Answer (score 0):

i assume you want:

the beach as background, the moon before that and the whirlwind before all.

So you have to make one image for each object. Your "whirlwind" and the beach are one object in your file. So you cannot have it before and behind the moon.

Comment: Yes, the whirlwind in front and behind it would be the moon and behind the moon is the background wallpaper of beach. I have now re-done the scene and each of the 3 objects have their own respective images assigned (see scene collection box). When you say that the whirlwind and beach are tied in as one object... is it because of this (circled issue): https://i2.paste.pics/79ddec9433752ddc9928955b2e2be978.png    If so, when I remove the beach image in that node setup, then I have an issue with the green screen removal: https://i2.paste.pics/13ef470e48966e87a2e011ea704f9160.png

Comment: Any ideas how to also fix the lack of the green screen removal as well as placing those objects in order of visibility mentioned earlier.